# typescript error TS2095: Could not find symbol 'gapi'

Tags: typescript, tsd

I am using Google API (gapi) in my client code, written in typescript.

For `gapi.auth.authorize` typescript gives error -

> error TS2095: Could not find symbol 'gapi'.

Now I have the gapi typing [gapi/gapi.d.ts](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/gapi/gapi.d.ts) installed correctly in my project. I checked the `gapi.d.ts`, it has below snippet-

```
declare module gapi.auth
```

Now I am confused why typescript compiler is giving error. Do I need to modify my code or the typing?

Answer (score 2):

The most common cause of this is that you added `gapi.d.ts` to your project, but didn't set its "Build Action" to "TypeScriptCompile". This causes the compiler/language service to ignore the file (much the same as if you had set a .cs file's Build Action to None).

[image]

Comment: I am using Webstorm for IDE and `grunt` for building project. Do you know solution for this scenario?

Comment: Sorry my bad, found the problem - the reference path `/// <reference path="../../typings/gapi/gapi.d.ts" />` was missing. Anyway thanks!